# <y test scripts are working fine in Eclipse but when i run it as runnable jar file , its not working ,

Tags: eclipse, testing, jar, runnable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlMyK.png)[Runnable jar is not executing from the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jxIB.png)
[The same test cases are working in eclipse][3]

can somebody tell me what's wrong here ,

Here is what happening :- 
1. I have 6 scripts , all are running fine in eclipse but when i make it runnable jar ( using eclipse ), 1 fails and 5 skip

Below is the CMD output
Command line suite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 5

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

2. My main class

```java
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestRunner {

    static TestNG testNg ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testNg= new TestNG();
        testNg.setTestClasses(new Class[] {LoginPageTest.class});
        testNg.run();
    }

}
```

3. My eclipse output
   Command line suite

   ## Total tests run: 5, Passes: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
4. I tried by hard coding everything though the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer ... while executing the jar file , driver was not getting initialize, hence i used webdrivermanager api and it worked